# Plotting Interpolations in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

It's apparently very simple but I can't find my mistake. The Plot gives me no points at all.

```
tmax = 1.;
nmax = 10;
deltat = tmax/nmax;
h[t_, s_] := t^2 + s^2;
T = Table[{{n*deltat}, {n*deltat}, h[n*deltat, n*deltat]}, {n, 0, nmax}]
inth = ListInterpolation[T]
Plot3D[inth[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Any help would be mostly welcome!

Marco

Answer (score 2):

I think your "T" is supposed to be a list of 3D points, in which case you should generate it with:

```
tmax = 1.;
nmax = 10;
deltat = tmax/nmax;
h[t_, s_] := t^2 + s^2;
T = Table[{n*deltat, n*deltat, h[n*deltat, n*deltat]}, {n, 0, nmax}]
inth = ListInterpolation[T]
Plot3D[inth[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Now T[[1]] = {0., 0., 0.} and not {{0.}, {0.}, 0.} as before.